# BGV for three multiplication level/depth

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Can BGV homomorphic encryption scheme support three multiplication level/depth with the help of key switching and modulus switching?

If Yes, how does one set up the parameter to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Actually It depends on which library you use. If you use Palisade, you can set numberoftowers (L level) to 3.

Comment: Using HELib, can the multiplicative level be set to 3?

Comment: You can set the `bits` parameter when you initialize the context and HElib should show you how many moduli you have in the chain which corresponds to the multiplication level. Here's an example https://github.com/homenc/HElib/blob/f0e3e010009c592cd411ba96baa8376eb485247a/examples/BGV_packed_arithmetic/BGV_packed_arithmetic.cpp#L33